# R: Plotting 2 Matrices in one plot

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have 2 Matrices as follows:

M1:

```
FY1301    FY1302   FY1303  FY1304   FY1305  FY1306
 146       56       159     129       54     535
 137      113       337     140      160     777
 281      111       331     198      231     875
 273       55       480     205      356     887
```

M2:

```
FY1301    FY1302   FY1303  FY1304   FY1305  FY1306
 34        5        99       82      121    180
 89       98       252       33      311    310
101       77       252       45      284    265
170       64       125       33      187    288
```

I am trying to plot both the matrices on same plot.

What I am currently doing is giving me 2 different plots. The following is the code:

```
par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 8.1), xpd=TRUE)
matplot(M1, type = c("b"), pch = 1, col=1:6, xlab = "Month", ylab = "Total Sessions With Med1")
legend("topright", legend = c("FY13 01","FY13 02","FY13 03","FY13 04","FY13 05","FY13 06"), inset=c(-0.11,0), col=1:6, pch=1, cex = 0.5, bty = "n")

par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 8.1), xpd=TRUE)
matplot(M2, type = c("b"), pch = 1, col=1:6, xlab = "Month", ylab = "Total Sessions Without Med1")
legend("topright", legend = c("FY13 01","FY13 02","FY13 03","FY13 04","FY13 05","FY13 06"), inset=c(-0.11,0), col=1:6, pch=1, cex = 0.5, bty = "n")
```

Since I would be comparing the two plots, I am looking to plot both the matrices in one single plot. (The matrices M1 and M2 are outputs of my code)

What modifications do I need to do to my current code?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 8.1), xpd=TRUE)

matplot(M1, type = c("b"), pch = 1, col=1:6, xlab = "Month", ylab = "Total Sessions With Med1")
    legend("topright", legend = c("FY13 01","FY13 02","FY13 03","FY13 04","FY13 05","FY13 06"), inset=c(-0.11,0), col=1:6, pch=1, cex = 0.5, bty = "n")

par(new = TRUE)

matplot(M2, type = c("b"), pch = 1, col=1:6, xlab = "Month", ylab = "Total Sessions Without Med1")
    legend("topright", legend = c("FY13 01","FY13 02","FY13 03","FY13 04","FY13 05","FY13 06"), inset=c(-0.11,0), col=1:6, pch=1, cex = 0.5, bty = "n")
```